# Elixir Session data after ajax call

Tags: authentication, session, axios, elixir

I'm using the Phoenix framework to build my application.
My users login with OAuth2, after which they are redirected to my webpage.
My application has a plug, which saves the user in a session variable:

```
  def call(conn, _) do

    user = get_session(conn, :user)
    
    #Find user in database
    case SmiksAanvraag.User_Functions.getUser(user) do
      result ->
        conn
              |> assign(:user, user)
              |> assign(:username, result)
              |> assign(:isAdmin, User_Functions.isAdmin(user))
      "" -> IO.inspect "Not logged in" 
            conn |> redirect(external: "http://www.localhost:4000/") |> halt()
    end
  end

  def login(conn, user) do
    conn
    |> assign(:user, Map.get(user, "username"))
    |> assign(:username, SmiksAanvraag.User_Functions.getUser(Map.get(user, "username")))
    |> put_session(:user, Map.get(user, "username"))
    |> configure_session(renew: true)
  end
```

This all works very well, until the user makes an Ajax call to the server (I'm using Axios). At that moment, the session information is lost.
What is the typical solution for this problem? What information do I (securely) pass through my Ajax call to inform the server the user is still logged on? At this moment, I make the following call:

```
        let req = axios.create({
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'x-csrf-token': document.head.querySelector("[name~=csrf-token][content]").content
            },
            params: {
                offset: me.state.offset,
                searchData: searchData
            }})
        req.get(`${Url.value}/api/getAllData`).then(response =>
        {
            this.setState({data: response.data.data, count: response.data.count})
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: typically you'll use a session cookie to track the sessions. Set the cookie (signed is best, or encrypted) when you authenticate someone. You didn't mention the server side frameworks you're using or I could give a more explicit answer.

Comment: I added it to my question (Phoenix).

Comment: Does the ajax request send the session cookie? it's typically named `_appname_key`

Comment: It does not send them, I changed my request with 'withCredentials: true' (see edit above). The cookie map remains empty. Do I need to send them manually? The cookies are present in the conn when the page is loaded.

Comment: well understanding why Axios is not sending the cookies is key to this problem. does the domain in the axios ajax request match the domain in the cookie?

Comment: I guess so, since the cookie IS sent when I don't use Ajax requests. 
 plug Plug.Session,
    store: :cookie,
    domain: "www.localhost",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it. My axios header was wrong... It should be 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'